# How to get ASCII characters when using choice command in batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I’m making a program in batch, and I want to use `choice` to make a username user input prompt. I want to be able to get ASCII characters, but I don't know how to get them. I know there is a way to get ASCII characters using the `type` command, but I only want to be able to get the characters that are on the keyboard like @£$ and stuff. How do I get ASCII characters as a choice, using `choice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I get ASCII characters as a choice, using choice?

> I only want to be able to get the characters that are on the keyboard like @£$

It is not possible as there is a restriction on the allowed characters.

Consider the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
choice /c @£$
pause
endlocal
```

If you run it you will see the following error:

```
> test
ERROR: Invalid choice. The valid choice characters are: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and ASCII values of 128 to 254.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So the allowed choice values are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and ASCII values of 128 to 254.

If you want to enter the ASCII characters directly use <kbd>alt</kbd> with the appropriate number, for example <kbd>alt156</kbd> will give you a `£`.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) - Accept user input to a batch file. Choice allows single key-presses to be captured from the keyboard.

Comment: "The keys you want to use are not a single key press." I think they might be on French keyboards.

Comment: @TRiG `@` is <alt-gr><@> so not a single key on a French AZERTY keyboard.

Comment: @DavidPostill then Shift-(any letter) wouldn't work either, but they do. So what you're saying that it is single key presses doesn't add up. As ( <alt-gr>+<2> = @ ) is only counted as one key press to the system. (the same goes with capital letters using shift)

Comment: And @TRiG i use QWERTY

Comment: @DavidPostill and this doesn't even have anything to do with my question. You answered that i CAN'T use £$€ but i can. I just don't know how to use ASCII codes with the CHOICE command. My question was never if £$€ would work, it was how i get ASCII codes.

Comment: @7h3w1z4rd It doesn't matter anyway as they are not in the list of allowed values.

Comment: @DavidPostill read my new comment... ^^

Comment: @7h3w1z4rd `@` is ascii 64. It is not in the list of allowed values for `choice`.

Comment: @DavidPostill the point was never EVEN to use £$€, they're just an example. The question is "How do i set ASCII codes as a input choice".

Comment: @7h3w1z4rd The same way you input them anywhere else. <alt> whatever. Eg <alt>+<156> > `£`

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, thank you. Thats what i wanted to know.